# how to aggregate 5 minute interval time series data into 15 minute intervals by averaging the the dependent variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large time series data set at five minute intervals. I want to increase the intervals to 15 and 30 minutes and have the 15 and 30 minute average for the dependent variables.

I have tried using the `dplyr cut` and `summarize` by `mean na.rm=TRUE` but it does not work and I get the following error message `"Factor 'time' contains implicit NA, consider using the 'forcats::fct_explicit_na'"`  *Being relatively new to R I am not sure what this means, but I don't understand why it won't work. I don't have NA's in my time column only in the dependent variable columns.*

**Here's my code:**
*(Also, `time, a, b, c, d` are column headers, `time` is in POSIXct format.)*

```
df %>%
    group_by(time=cut(time, breaks="15 min"))) %>%
    summarize(a = mean(a, na.rm=TRUE), b = mean(b, na.rm=TRUE),
    c = mean(c, na.rm=TRUE), d = mean(d, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I expect to get an aggregated time series with intervals of 15 minutes instead of 5 and the average of each of those 15 minute intervals show up in the dependent variables but i just get that error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, t2 = cut.POSIXt(x = time, breaks = "15 mins")) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(t2) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(am = mean(a, na.rm = T),
                   bm = mean(b, na.rm = T),
                   cm = mean(c, na.rm = T),
                   dm = mean(d, na.rm = T))
```